# htaccess rewrite rule for redirecting and removing extensions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my `.htaccess` file I have these rewrites

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^/admin/$ http://socialable.comuv/admin.php [R=301,L]
#noted out three lines since it's not what I need anymore I forgot the RewriteRule originally
```

Yet now it seems to not work at all, it keeps giving errors everywhere. I want is this

/admin/ (directory) to become /admin.php (file)
   administration.php to become /administration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin.php [R,L]
RewriteRule ^administration\.php administration [R,L]
```

Once you are satisfied that the redirect works, you can change the `R` to `R=301` to make it permanent.

Comment: Ok I've gotten these to work, but I need to get if the user types `/admin` which is a directory to redirect to `/admin.php` instead

Comment: Also why are your flags `[R,L]` and then `[L,R]` ? I don't know what they mean just curious though.

Comment: Regarding the flags: no reason, just came out that way. :) Regarding your redirection for `admin`: you mean, you don't want to go to `http://example.com/admin.php`, just `admin.php` ?

Comment: Keep first rule as `RewriteRule ^admin/?$ /admin.php [NC,L]` (no leading slash)

Comment: @zx81 no you have it wrong on that lol. I don't want to go to `/admin` because its a directory, but above that is `/admin.php` which I want if the user types that (basically really going to the directory I want it to go to the page.

Comment: Edited the answer. Not sure I fully understood the requirement, so take a look. :)

Comment: The RegExp you have for the rewrite doesn't that state that there is something leading after `/`? I suck at this I tell ya, it's about the only language I haven't tried learning in.

Comment: I think the bet would be to add a `.htaccess` to that folder

Comment: Now 2nd rule is not really needed.

Comment: @anubhava You're probably right, I'm just not 100% sure of the requirements. The second rule is still there in case he has `admin/something` for which he wants a special redirect.

Comment: @anubhava Rereading it, I thing you're right. When EasyBB said `/admin/ (directory)`, I thought he meant `admin/somefolder`, but it looks like he just meant the `admin` folder. That clears it up, indeed if that's the case we don't need that second rule. Thank you.

Comment: so I added a second htaccess to my /admin/ directory which has `Redirect /admin/ http://socialable.comuv.com/admin.php` which now rewrites everything even like this `admin/administration.php` to this `admin.phpadministration.php`

Comment: Hey EasyBB, no please don't add an `.htaccess` in the admin folder. Looks like thanks to anu's keen eyes we're now all on the same page. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: +1 this should work now and yes remove that admin/.htaccess :)

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, taking a break from answering—might come back for an hour sometime later—see you. :)

Comment: Not working correctly. I still need `/admin/administration.php` to work fine. The only thing I want is if the user types `www.socialable.comuv.com/admin` or `.../admin/` to redirect to `../admin.php` it's leading to `../admin/admin.php`

Comment: nevermind :o I had a header leading to `../admin/admin.php` like a fool! Thanks guys